# Why does a table not clear a float when it can't fit next to the floated element?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Test case ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KP8g9/)):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>table float</title>
<style>
    div
    {
        background-color: #006666;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 75%;
        width: 25%;
    }

    table
    {
        background-color: #006699;
    }
</style>
<div>
    div
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In Firefox, the `table` is to the right of the `div` even though it can't fit next to it. In Chrome and IE, the `table` is below the `div`.

Firefox 30:

> [image: Firefox 30 screenshot]

Chrome 35:

> [image: Chrome 35 screenshot]

IE 11:

> [image: IE 11 screenshot]

Why is this and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox, reported in February 2009: [Bug 478834 - table following left float doesn't clear it even if it can't fit next to it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=478834)

A workaround is to simply clear the float ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMUQ6/)):

```
table
{
    background-color: #006699;
    clear: left;
}
```

> [image: Firefox screenshot]